# how can I open another window or tab and fire some specific query in for that window and after execution close that window

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, google-chrome-extension, window

I am making an application, where I have array containing URLs and I want to go to every URLs and fire my java script using extension.

I referred W3school for this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_close).

Please help me with this how can I solve this basic problem I am not able to solve.

Comment: What do you mean by “go to”?

Comment: It might help us understand what exactly is required if you could show us the code you have so far.  Do you want to set up a new window for each url, allow it to load and then remove it?